# Can someone infringe my invention by reordering the steps?

Tags: claims

My claims looks like this

```
A system for X comprising:
      Step 1
      Step 2
      Step 3
      Step 4
```

Can someone infringing my invention by reordering the steps?

```
A system for X comprising:
      Step 1
      Step 3
      Step 2
      Step 4
```

Comment: By the way, a system shouldn't be defined by method steps. There are plenty of excemptions and everyone ignores it, but sometimes the patent examiners don't let you do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends if your claims cover only the exact order or any order.

Example:

> A method of doing steps 1 and 2.

Covers doing steps 1 and 2 in any order.

> A method of doing steps 1 and 2 subsequently.

Doesn't.

Comment: Depending on the actual actions involved "A method of doing steps 1 and 2" may inherently imply an order.

Comment: I have seen "in any operative order" as a way to be explicit about the flexibility of order.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite if the steps can't be done in another order (without changing the steps), then they can't be done in another order anyways ;)

Comment: Overcoming whatever issues required a specific order would be fertile ground for a new patent, assuming all of the other requirements for patentability are met.